# Running OpenGL app without desktop

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi, raspbian, opengl

Is it possible to run an opengl application like `glxgears` from the command line without starting a desktop environment?

It should directly go to exclusive full screen mode.

Comment: I would say: put `glxgears -fullscreen` alone in `~/.xinitrc` and then run `startx`, that would be a good start.

Comment: thanks, but i should mention that i dont have any xwindow desktop installed, so the command `startx` is not available

Comment: Opengl can't run without X, at least not standalone, maybe there are other "window systems", like wayland or mir but you still need something. Also I doubt you'd get accelerated opengl without any X (proprietary) drivers.

Comment: Also opengl depends on X so if you have glxgears, you have X (hence the x in glXgears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to run an application meant for X in the command line.

But like @cylgalad said, you can have any desktop environment and put that application to run exclusively.

Try to install a lightweight desktop environment, like xfce or fluxbox.

Comment: I don't think you actually need any DE or WM at all for that purpose.

Comment: yep, i only needed to install xserver and xinit.